# Multi picklist again

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, picklist, multi-select

I have implemented a functionality where in multi picklist values are populated via code.

But when the user deselects the values in the multi picklist the value gets deleted instead of being shown in the left(unselected) list.

Can anyone please help me out with this quickly ?

UPDATE @ ALL : Take it as a simple trigger code that updates multipicklist field with values in a map. Ex : Multipicklist__c = get map values;

The values are not a part of multi picklist values. I wanted it to be dynamic. The values worked fine earlier.

Comment: Please provide what you have implemented so far so that we can help.

Comment: Hi MEXI. I doubt anyone will be able to help you with this without seeing the code you are using to actually perform this action. Would you be able to edit your question and provide that?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you put in picklist some value that is not one of possible choices on this multipicklist.
Please check that out.